# How to get the value of var cast in this query postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have the problem when create select insert loop in procedure postgresql. The problem is var cast('1000/1902/003' AS TEXT) always null. How to detect this variabel? i realy need this variabel.

I have try without casting but the parameter always read as integer.

```
BEGIN

        FOR tx IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM T_DataUpload2_FinalDetail WHERE dataupload2fd_id = CAST('|| 1000/1902/003 ||'AS TEXT)'

    LOOP
        data_cust := tx.DataUpload2FD_DistID; 
  data_dist := tx.DataUpload2FD_CustID;
        RETURN NEXT;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dynamic SQL to begin with?

```
BEGIN
  FOR tx IN SELECT * 
            FROM T_DataUpload2_FinalDetail 
            WHERE dataupload2fd_id = '1000/1902/003'
  LOOP
    data_cust := tx.DataUpload2FD_DistID; 
    data_dist := tx.DataUpload2FD_CustID;
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The expression (without quotes) `1000/1902/003` means "1000 divided by 1902 divided by 3" the result would be `0,175...` which is rounded to `0` (**not** `null`) because all values are integers and thus integer division is used.